# pyqt4 change spinbox value from another spinbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I use `pyqt4` to create simple application.

I add a new button to lock values of the two spinboxes. When I change the first value the second changed automatically after lock,
something like lock camera width/height in 3d applications.

At the same time the image of the button must change between lock and unlock icons.

I tried a lot with

```
self.spin_btn.toggled.connect(self.lock_unlock) #lock_ unlock is the def
```

but I always get wrong results.

[image]

Comment: Please explain better, I do not understand what you want. :P

Comment: I recommend not talking about cameras or other things, for example describes the initial state of the QDoubleSpinBox and the button, and then it would happen if the button is pressed.